# How can I get the MIME types of objects in Amazon S3?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to retrieve the MIME types of the objects in S3. I am trying to implement a solution in which I will be getting multiple objects from S3. Instead of using there key and then getting a sub string to calculate the MIME type, can I get the MIME type from Amazon S3 in some way? I am using cloud berry explorer pro and I know it let's you set the MIME type, but how do we retrieve this information using the AWS SDK for .NET or the REST API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The REST API offers the [HEAD Object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) operation for this purpose and the [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) conveniently wraps the very same functionality via the [GetObjectMetadata()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client_GetObjectMetadata.htm) method:

> The GetObjectMetadata operation is used to retrieve information about
>   a specific object or object size, without actually fetching the object
>   itself. **This is useful if you're only interested in the object
>   metadata**, and don't want to waste bandwidth on the object data. **The
>   response is identical to the GetObject response, except that there is
>   no response body.** *[emphasis mine]*

Comment: I am not sure if HEAD OBJECT will get it but I found a solution to it. Please find my answer below.

Comment: It is actually very easy to get the MIME type of objects stored in S3. All you have to do is
response  = _s3.GetObject(request);
string MIMEtype = response.ContentType;
response.ContentType will then get the MIME type from s3. We are using Cloud berry explorer pro to upload objects and to maintain our s3 account. It has a lot of default MIME types and it assigns that to objects as you upload them. You can also add your own MIME types. You can specify the extension and the MIME type, so the next time you upload something it automatically assigns a MIME type to that object.

Comment: @Abhi.Net: While `GetObject()` works fine in principle, @Roman is correct to suggest HEAD resp. `GetObjectMetadata()` here, which is significantly more efficient for your use case - see my update to his answer for details.

Comment: Thank you guys for your solution. Now, I know when to choose GetObject() and GetobjectMetaData(). Although in my case I have to retrieve the objects(Diff types- css, html,jpeg, gif, flash) so I will have to go with GetObject() but 'll keep GetGetobjectMetaData() in my mind in case I just need the meta data.

Answer (score 5):

To get the file and mimeType of the file in the same request...

```
using (var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(region))
{
    var response = client.GetObject(bucket, key);
    var mimeType = response.Headers.ContentType;
    return new StreamWithMimeType(response.ResponseStream, mimeType); 
}
```

Comment: `HeadersCollection` has a property `ContentType` specifically. I suggest you use that instead of a string index.

Comment: I think it should be simply `var mimeType = response.Headers.ContentType;`

Comment: @Bartosz Agreed. Edited.